# Pseudocode for min, max and avg temperatures

Tags: arrays, max, pseudocode, min, average

I'm not a experienced programmer (yet), but I'm applying to a school that has several coding courses.

In the entrance examination however, there may be solvable problems that must be written in pseudocode or as flow charts. Somewhat I handle the flow charts, but I'm having a hard time making the pseudocode look good.

For example, I tried to write a pseudocode for a program that scans 24 temperature readings and prints out MIN, MAX and AVG, but I don't think I did so well. I got this far, but didn't get the AVG in:

```
 max = 0 min = 0 set up array of a[24] loop start    if  a[x] > max
        max = a[x]
        else if a[x] < min
        min = a[x]

 print Max temp: print Min temp:
```

I would like to see how you guys would construct a clear pseudocode of this program.

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I have flagged it for migration.

Comment: @mnel, this is not on-topic for codereview. Firstly, its not real code (it's pseudocode), secondly, it's not working code (the implementation isn't finished.)

Comment: @WinstonEwert - thanks for clearing that up. Never noticed the "no pseudo code" rule in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smaller statements tend to be better.  I'd rewrite your provided snippet as:

```
count = 24
temperatures is an array of count elements
max = -9999
min = 9999
total = 0

for each value in temperatures
    total = total + value
    if value > max
        max = value
    else if value < min
        min = value

print "Minimum: " min
print "Maximum: " max
print "Average: " total / count
```

It's almost real python code.  The following is real python code:

```
count = 24
temperatures = [3 * x for x in range(count)]
max = -9999
min = 9999
total = 0.0

for value in temperatures:
    total = total + value
    if value > max:
        max = value
    if value < min:
        min = value

print("Minimum: ", min)
print("Maximum: ", max)
print("Average: ", total / count)
```

Comment: FWIW you should probably be using -inf and inf, rather any arbitrary large (or small) values, as inf and -inf will always fail inequality test (in the right direction, of course. inf is always larger then anything and everything is smaller then it, for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
max:= 0
min:= (some big number)

while i < 24
begin
   if a[i] < min then min = a[i]
   if a[i] > max then max = a[i]
   sum = sum + a[i]
end

print min, max, sum/24
```

If I were you, I probably write something like this. I am not arguing that it is perfect, but at least it is something to work on.